# Can I adjust the relative influence of observations in a mixed model in nlme or lme4?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, lm, weights

Is there an equivalent of lm's "weights" argument for nlme or lme4 ?

Here's an example to illustrate my question in case it isn't clear enough:
I have data taken from 3-5 trees at 3 sites. From each tree, two samples are collected from the Upper, Middle and Lower sections of the tree's crown, and a pathogen's disease severity is assessed and recorded for each sample. However, at some sites the upper level of the crown was too hard to reach, so fewer/no samples were collected from the upper crown section. The level of infection can be variable between the crown sections, but no significant differences can be found with an ANOVA as there are too many 0s and therefore the normality & variance homogeneity assumptions of ANOVA aren't met. For now, I have decided to average the disease severity values at the tree level and use that average as my response variable. These tree averages are therefore not all based on the same number of observations. To illustrate this, below is a table (not real data) of the number of observations from the Lower (L), Middle (M) and Upper (U) crown sections, which are summed to obtain the weight (wgt) of each tree. Severity is the average disease severity for the whole tree and Temp is the temperature at the site (same for all trees at 1 site).

```
  Tree             L M U wgt Severity Temp
  Site1_Tree1      2 2 0 4   0.1      1
  Site1_Tree2      2 2 0 4   0.2      1
  Site1_Tree3      2 2 0 4   0.12     1
  Site2_Tree1      2 2 0 4   0.1      5
  Site2_Tree2      2 2 0 4   0.15     5
  Site2_Tree3      2 2 1 5   0.4      5
  Site2_Tree4      2 2 1 5   0.31     5
  Site3_Tree1      2 2 2 6   0.2      3
  Site3_Tree2      2 2 2 6   0.1      3
  Site3_Tree3      2 2 1 5   0.05     3
```

I want to run a linear mixed model to see if temperature has an effect on disease severity in lme or lme4. I want the influence of each observation to vary according to its wgt value, as I want trees based on a higher number of observations to have more influence on the model than trees with a lower number of observations. From what I understand, this is what the "weights" function in lm does, but in lme it is used to specify variance structure.
Any help is appreciated ! Thank you !